# Index file contents of unknown file type

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I would like to index the file contents of unknown file types. This window allows you to change settings for a particular file type, but I want to avoid doing that with each file type I have that is not known to Windows.

> [image: index]

I have used the registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown
```

before but I do not see how to use it in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [someone else asked this question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-index-and-search-contents-of-an-unknown/434d2de0-ecd9-4253-bce3-b5bb3129fba8), the response from a Microsoft MVP was to *use a third-party program*. Apparently even Microsoft acknowledges that the search function in Windows Vista+ is useless.

Windows uses two different registry entries for file-types. There is an entry for the actual extension which in turn, points to a corresponding file-type entry.

For example, text-files will have an entry at `hkcr\.txt` which will contain a reference to `txtfile` that points to `hkcr\txtfile` which has type-specific information. (Multiple extensions can point to the same type; e.g., `.cpp` or `.mytype` can point to `txtfile` to have them treated like text files).

If you use a registry-activity monitor (e.g., with Process Monitor), you can watch the Indexer enumerate and access `HKCR`’s sub-keys. Unfortunately the Indexer does not access the type-specific entries which is what `unknown` is. It only enumerates *extensions*, and since unknown types have no extension (well they do, but they vary), there is no way to manually register unknown types with the indexer.

That said, indexing unknown types *was* [doable in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309173#tocHeadRef) (figure 1). You can try using the same option in Windows 7:

1. Open the registry-editor
2. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ContentIndex\FilterFilesWithUnknownExtensions
   ```
3. Locate the DWORD value `FilterFilesWithUnknownExtensions` or create one if none exists
4. Assign it a value of `1` to index unknown types or `0` to turn off unknown type indexing
5. Restart the *Windows Search* service

If that still doesn’t work, then I’m afraid the ability to index the contents of unknown files has simply been removed from the indexer in Vista and up.

---

**Figure 1**: Windows XP’s unknown-type indexing option

[image: Indexing unknown types in XP]

Comment: I am accepting this because of the effort, but it appears that the feature was removed as you said.

Comment: Unfortunately, they made a lot of undesirable changes in Vista and did not revert them in 7. They just don’t listen to user feedback. `:-|`

Answer (score 0):

The free and popular Notepad++ has a useful feature to search file content within a directory, recursively. I use it often. Scans all text files, including unknown file types.

Additional feature: well integrated with Notepad++. The entire matching line is show in search result, with the target phrase highlighted. Click any line to open the file in Notepad++.

It treats binary file content as a bunch of funny characters.

It takes time when searching big files, but it doesn't crash.

This solution doesn't use indexing, but solves the problem nevertheless.